# Control MoveHub (Boost) and Mindstorms Inventor Hub over one app

Tags: mindstorms, compatibility, boost, robot-inventor

I'd like to control Lego Boost (Move)Hub and the mindstorms inventor hub with one app. I know that it is probably possible with python, but my son is not yet ready to programm in a fully fledged development environment.

Consequently, I'd like to provide him a scratch like environment where he can work with both hubs at the same time. E.g. creating a joystick with Boost that controls a mindstorms robot.

Could someone point me to the right direction.

Comment: I'm thinking this open source code here: https://github.com/NStrijbosch/hub2hub/tree/main/examples/MoveHub

Comment: Thanks @Eric, you are right, there is a python integration (also see [pybricks](https://pybricks.com/)), but I am searching for something scratch-like for younger children.

Comment: Okie I don't have a Prime Hub and the hub myself but I have replied to Alex, zovits, Philo etc.

Comment: delayed by all.

Comment: erm...............................

Comment: Hi, Eric - I don't get your point. At the moment it is just us two commenting on that question. Who is delaying what? So I do not see any comments from "Alex, zovits, Philo etc" as you have been writing. Are they hidden?

Comment: defiantly a user lol

Comment: ???????........

Comment: erm, i found this: https://bricklife.com/scratch-gui/

Comment: Ok, here it is a link

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since November 2023, Pybricks now includes a block programming language that works with most Powered Up hubs, including BOOST, and MINDSTORMS Robot Inventor. This also includes Bluetooth communications that is compatible between all hubs.

As of this writing, the blocks are in beta and require a paid subscription.